# Moving full screen apps between monitors shortcut

Tags: keyboard, applescript, display, bettertouchtool

Does anyone know if it is possible to move a full screen app to another monitor using a shortcut? Or if there is no existing shortcut would it be possible with Applescript?

BetterTouchTool has "Move window to next monitor" as one of its predefined actions but this only works on desktops and not with full-screen apps.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Simon

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com)?

[Here](http://joseherran.info/blog/2014/10/11/move-cursor-and-window-through-screens/) is an example of how I deal with moving windows through screens. I just tried to move full screens apps -never tried before- and seems that didn't work well. But you could modify my macros to `Exit full screen` before moving to the next screen and `Enter full screen` after that. The macro for that is called `Type a Keystroke`.